# SpringBoot Integration flow application closing on start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to figure out why does my spring boot application stop, given the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class FirestoreCommandIntegrationFlow {
    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow registerInboundAdapter() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
                .transform("hello"::equals)
                .handle(m -> System.err.println("work"))
                .get();
    }
}
```

What im trying to figure out is why does the application just stop without any errors, it starts normal and then after few seconds it just drops the subscription to the "input" channel and closes the flow.
I know this is probably a silly question but i just can't find a reason why does the application stop. I've been folowing the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference and as i understood it, my flow should keep on listening to the "input" channel and the flow should keep running.

NOTE: My springboot app has web server disabled with `spring.main.web-environment=false` in application.properties

Log:

```
2019-01-09 13:32:21.261  INFO 12658 --- [           main] c.r.t.m.Application                      : Starting Application on ...
2019-01-09 13:32:21.265  INFO 12658 --- [           main] c.r.t.m.Application                      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-09 13:32:21.348  INFO 12658 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@625732: startup date [Wed Jan 09 13:32:21 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-09 13:32:21.744  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.c.IntegrationRegistrar             : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2019-01-09 13:32:22.025  INFO 12658 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2019-01-09 13:32:22.030  INFO 12658 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2019-01-09 13:32:22.199  INFO 12658 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b59005e8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-09 13:32:22.446  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2019-01-09 13:32:22.854  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-01-09 13:32:22.863  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Starting beans in phase 0
2019-01-09 13:32:22.863  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2019-01-09 13:32:22.863  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel          : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-09 13:32:22.864  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2019-01-09 13:32:22.864  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'input' channel
2019-01-09 13:32:22.864  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.c.DirectChannel                    : Channel 'application.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-09 13:32:22.864  INFO 12658 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-09 13:32:22.872  INFO 12658 --- [           main] c.r.t.m.Application                      : Started Application in 2.032 seconds (JVM running for 2.652)
2019-01-09 13:32:22.874  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@625732: startup date [Wed Jan 09 13:32:21 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-09 13:32:22.876  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Stopping beans in phase 0
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'input' channel
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.c.DirectChannel                    : Channel 'application.input' has 0 subscriber(s).
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel          : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2019-01-09 13:32:22.877  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2019-01-09 13:32:22.878  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-01-09 13:32:22.878  INFO 12658 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Spring applications require a server like tomee/tomcat that keep running and are ready to listen. Spring already contains these embedded containers to be used as servers... can you look up configuration in your build file for this. Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: Im using gradle and springboot app has web server disabled with spring.main.web-environment=false in application.properties, i was hoping spring will keep on running without the web server. I understood that the flow will keep on going while there is at least one subscriber to the input channel(which there is)

Comment: Also if you dont want a web application and run periodically, add this "EnableScheduling"  annotation before "SpringBootApplication" annotation in main. You can also add "Scheduled", if that doesnt work.

Comment: @EnableScheduling(initialDelay = 100, fixedRate = 100)
public void run() {
    System.out.println("debug print time -->" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}

Comment: >`Spring applications require a server like tomee/tomcat that keep running and are ready to listen.`  That is not correct; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flow does nothing; it is static, and does nothing on its own; it has no dynamic components (pollers, message-driven adapters); it needs something to send data to it, on a thread; e.g. the main thread, or some other non-daemon thread.

e.g.

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel input) {
    return args -> {
        while (true) {
            input.send(someMessage);
            Thread.sleep(1_000);
        }
    }
}
```

This will run on the main thread after starting.

Comment: I tried the next option and still isn't working, instead of using IntegrationFlows.from("input"), I declared ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer and then IntegrationFlows.from(producer)..., wouldn't that be a dynamic component that is listening to events of certain type, so the flow shouldn't stop?

Comment: Again, that is a passive component - it is called by Spring Framework when an event is published; you need something active, like a polled inbound channel adapter, or some message-driven adapter (JMS, RabbitMQ, etc) that creates a non-daemon thread to emit messages.

Comment: Ah I get it what i screwed up. For my use case i need an event-driven-inbound-adapter(listener) that will listen to custom events (live firestore changes). I've came upon https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/amqp/AmqpTests.java that looks like a good example of what to do. Thanks for clarifying the problem.

Comment: You can also do `System.in.read()` in the `main()` method, which will block until someone hits enter on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If yours isnt a web application and still want to continue to listen/ run periodically. Try adding annotation

> @EnableScheduling

or

> @Scheduled

to your main application or some sample task runner

```
@EnableScheduling(initialDelay = 100, fixedRate = 100)public void run(){System.out.println("debug print time -->" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());}
```

This can be applied to SpringApplication context as well.